# Is the pipe '|' in shell the ordinary pipe?

Tags: unix, operating-system, pipe

On page 145 of Operating System Concepts (Avi Silberschatz, 9th edition), it states that

> **Note that ordinary pipes require a parent–child relationship between the communicating processes on both UNIX and Windows systems**. This
>   means that these pipes can be used only for communication between
>   processes on the same machine.

However, when I execute the command `ps -el | grep 0` on a linux machine, both processes ps and grep have bash as their parent process. Other resources confirms that the shell pipe is an ordinary pipe that is unidirectional. If a parent-child relationship is required, how come the ps and grep process are siblings under bash? Just to confirm my understanding about pipes, is the statement in the textbook simply wrong or have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: Sorry, but voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Put another way, StackOverflow is to help people fix their programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, but must be interpreted mixing with descriptor inheritance.  What it means is that to setup a piping you need a parent-child relationship, not that communication with pipe is only possible between parent and children. So in your case, bash creates the pipe and transmit it to both children ps and grep (one writing in it while the other reads). Thus, both children communicates with the a pipe created by their parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess we could create an "ordinary pipe" between two independent processes if we can share the pipe descriptors between them, but that would be reinventing the named pipe.